# Is there a way to view the code behind a python syntax?

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to grab the html source code of website webpages using urllib3 in python. I'm trying to view how the .read() function was coded so that I can replicate it to get the source code of websites without calling it. My code is:

```
def scan(url):
    x = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    print(x.read())


scan("https://www.google.com")
```

So I just want to see the code behind x.read().

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: If you're in `ipython`/`jupyter` and the underlying code is in python, you can try `x.read??` to pop up the source code.

Comment: Some IDEs will allow ctrl + click (or similar) to go to a function declaration, including imported ones. Otherwise you can probably find the source code online, such as https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/urllib/request.py

Comment: Try dir(x.read) or help(x.read) to get further details of the properties and methods of the object.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can [view the source code for urllib](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/urllib/request.py), the library that contains the `urlopen` function. You can find this link from the [official documentation for urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) (the link to the source is at the top of the article).

As the comment for `urlopen` indicates for your case:

> For HTTP and HTTPS URLs, this function returns a http.client.HTTPResponse
> object slightly modified.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) for http.client links to [this source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/http/client.py), where you can perform a find for `def read(` and arrive at [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/http/client.py#L450).